# React icons - Change background color

Tags: css, reactjs, react-icons

Currently working with react-icons on a website and having trouble with svg's and styling.

What I've tried so far is using the React-Icons `{IconContext.Provider}` as shown on the git repo as well as using the `fill`, `stroke`. I've also tried to add a CSS Class with context provider and then set the background colour of the svg with the CSS property in a module, but this doesn't seem to work either.

What is the easiest way to set the background color of the SVG?

With stroke and fill it only colours the actual icon itself since that's were the vectors are being drawn.

`Icon` is being passed in as a prop to the `StyledCard`.

```
 <StyledCard
     heading="Express"
     techIcon={<FaAngleDoubleRight color="#808080" size={80} stroke="black" strokeWidth=".3"/>} />
```

Answer (score 0):

use `currentColor` inside stroke, it will replace by parent color.

Example:

```
<StyledCard
     heading="Express"
     techIcon={<FaAngleDoubleRight size={80} stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth=".3"/>} 
/>
```